# Devilspie on Wayland

Tags: gnome3, wayland, devilspie

I have just upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10 and I'm now using Gnome 3 native over Wayland.  My problem is that I have been using [devilspie](http://www.nongnu.org/devilspie2/) to place windows on the screen in the desired position.  I also use the [Auto Move Windows](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/16/auto-move-windows/) extension to place the windows on the right workspace.

Does anyone know of an extension or similar that can position the windows on Wayland the way devilspie can on Xorg?

Comment: "Approaching 2022" update: I'm still not finding any Gnome window rule engine for Wayland :/

Comment: The "official" feature request is over here: https://github.com/dsalt/devilspie2/issues/7.  There is also https://savannah.nongnu.org/bugs/?46746. To support my claim https://www.nongnu.org/devilspie2/ says: 

> Development is (theoretically) done on savannah, so check out the git [repository on savannah](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/devilspie2.git), as well as the bug tracker and other stuff in the [project page](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/devilspie2/). **However**, do also check [this repository on Github](https://github.com/dsalt/devilspie2) as it may well be more active.

Comment: How do you feel about writing a gnome extension for that? I'm keen to writing one, but not sure about doing that on my own, maybe we can approach this in an open source project if more people wants to participate. Ideally someone with specific knowledge on gnome extensions.